# Как получить данную тень?

Tags: html, css

если в макете дан только fill 4F4C75

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в сети много генераторов теней (например https://active-vision.ru/icon/box-shadow/) - можете поиграться с параметрами и найти нужные себе параметры

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 42px 42px -21px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 42px 42px -21px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 42px 42px -21px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#4F4C75` не похож на серый, скорее всего, вы что-то перепутали

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.position {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block {
  background-color: rgb(266, 266, 266);
  border: 3px solid rgb(79, 76, 117);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5vw 0px rgb(79, 76, 117);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block position"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите варианты разных теней здесь
https://getcssscan.com/css-box-shadow-examples

Думаю, что такую тень правильней создавать не одним стилевым свойством box-shadow, а набором его свойств, типа:

```
box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px 1px 1px 0px inset, rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 50px 100px -20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 30px 60px -30px;
```